# SwiftUI "Cannot find 'ObservableObject' in scope" in function, where the 'ObservableObject' is a parameter

Tags: swiftui

In my function, I have a parameter a `manager: TextManager`, but when I try to bind its text to a `Binding<String>`, it says "Cannot find '$manager' in scope". Why cannot it find the 'manager', it is right there in the function parameter?

The main UI code is the following:

```
struct BugView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var textManager = TextManager(limit: 30)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("line 1")
            
            fetchTextView(title:"Name", manager: textManager)
            
            Text("line 3")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func fetchTextView(title: String, manager : TextManager) -> some View {
        TextField(title, text: $manager.text) // <- Cannot find '$manager' in scope
        

        Text("\(manager.text.count)/\(manager.characterLimit)")
    }
}
```

where the `TextManager` is the following

```
class TextManager: ObservableObject {
    let characterLimit: Int

    @Published var text = "" {
        didSet {
            if text.count > characterLimit && oldValue.count <= characterLimit {
                text = oldValue
            }
        }
    }

    init(limit: Int = 10) {
        characterLimit = limit
    }
}
```

I started with this code, and it works fine

```
struct BugView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var textManager = TextManager(limit: 30)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("line 1")
            
            TextField("good case", text: $textManager.text)
            
            Text("line 3")
        }
    }
    
}
```

I just want to wrap the some text view generation logic inside a function because I would have multiple of those views, and I would like to avoid code duplication.

Comment: `manager` is not the same as `$manager` -- the `$` is special syntactic sugar based on the `ObservedObject` property wrapper. The solution you came up with looks like a good one.

Comment: I would like to add stuff before and after my `TextField`, such as boarder, character count, text style, etc. Then I would have multiple of these `TextField`. I don't want to copy and paste those same attribute for every single on of those `TextField`s. So I want to wrap them in a function, and only change the part needs to be changed.

Comment: Either make a `ViewModifier` or make a separate component. Or, have the function take a binding, not the ObservableObject itself.

Comment: For academic purpose, why does the `ObservableObject` not work here?

Comment: Because the property wrapper gives it extra syntactic sugar. It doesn't have that in the version passed into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is `TextManager` is a class instead of struct. We only need reference types in SwiftUI if we are doing something asynchronous like saving or syncing data (although `.task` removes that need for most use cases).

```
struct TextManager {
    let characterLimit: Int
    var text = "" {
        didSet {
            if text.count > characterLimit && oldValue.count <= characterLimit {
                text = oldValue
            }
        }
    }

    init(limit: Int = 10) {
        characterLimit = limit
    }

    mutating func reset() {
        text = ""
    }
}
```

In a struct, any change to its properties, like `text` is detected as a change to the whole struct, which is a feature that SwiftUI takes advantage of in its design. For logic you might want to test, you can use `mutating func`.

Next, instead of a `@ViewBuilder func` you need a custom subview, e.g.

```
struct FetchTextView: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var config: TextManager

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: $config.text) 
        Text("\(config.text.count)/\(config.characterLimit)")       
    }
}
```

`@Binding var` instead of `let` gives us write access to the state, but as with `let`, `body` is also called when the value changes. The reason is breaking up the View struct hierarchy into small Views makes SwiftUI more efficient and faster, if you use funcs you risk breaking its dependency tracking (which is how SwiftUI decides if body should be called based on any used values changing). Use it like:

```
@State var config = TextManager()

FetchTextView(title: title, config: $config)
```

Answer (score -1):

To use `ObservableObject` in function, you will have to create manual binding instead of the syntactic sugar `$`. The following code would work

```
    @ViewBuilder
    private func fetchTextView(title: String, manager: TextManager) -> some View {
        let binding = Binding(
            get: { manager.text },
            set: { manager.text = $0 }
        )

        TextField(title, text: binding)


        Text("\(manager.text.count)/\(manager.characterLimit)")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

why can't we use it like this
just pass textManager directly instead pass via fetchTextView Method

```
struct BugView: View {
    
    @StateObject var textManager = TextManager(limit: 30) // <-- when creating an instance make sure use StateObject
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("line 1")
            
            fetchTextView(title:"Name")
            
            Text("line 3")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func fetchTextView(title: String) -> some View {
        TextField(title, text: $textManager.text) // <-- just use textManagerDirectly...
        Text("\(textManager.text.count)/\(textManager.characterLimit)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of creating the `fetchTextView` function. Suppose we want to have 3 text field in the view, we would declare `@StateObject var nameManager = TextManager()`, `@StateObject var addressManager = TextManager()`, and `@StateObject var phoneManager = TextManager()`. With the original implementation of `fetchTextView`, we just need to call `fetchTextView("name", nameManager)`,`fetchTextView("address", addressManager)` and `fetchTextView("phone", phoneManager)`. And these views would all have a word count below. But your approach would require 3 different functions.